# "Tight" filling of multi-line text in node

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need to label curved paths with multi-line labels. Currently, I do this by placing nodes along the paths as in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[class=minimal,border=0pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[-] (-1,-0.5) .. controls (-1,1) and (1,0) .. 
    node[fill=yellow,above left=-20pt and -11pt,align=center] 
    {short line\\much longer line} (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which gives

[image]

Normally, I use `fill=white`, but here I have used yellow to make the problem clearer: The node is as wide as the longest line, which means that part of the line is obscured by the label.

What I want instead is that only the immediate background of the text is filled. For multi-line text, this would mean that the filling depends not on the width of the widest line, but that the filling would adjust to the width of each individual line, i.e., it would be "tight". I don't know how to do this in an elegant way with `TikZ`, but this MWE shows something close to what I want:

```
\documentclass[class=minimal,border=0pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[-] (-1,-0.5) .. controls (-1,1) and (1,0) .. (1,1);
  \coordinate (L) at (-0.9,0.2);  
  \draw (L) node[fill=yellow,above=0pt,align=center] {short line};  
  \draw (L) node[fill=yellow,below=0pt,align=center] {much longer line};  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

resulting in:

[image]

There are at least two problems with this:

- There's white space between the two lines. I could get rid of it by moving the labels manually, but this is tedious, and the spacing between the lines would not necessarily be consistent with the usual line spacing.
- I need to manually place the label rather than being able to place it along the path as in the first MWE.

What's a good solution that circumvents these problems?

Comment: Does the node need to be sloped (i.e. rotated along the path)? How many lines will you need? Just two? The white space comes from `outer sep`. Set it to `0pt` or also `draw=yellow` the nodes. Do you actually want to “paint” over the line or would you rather have the line not even be drawn there?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: I don't need for the node to be sloped. I only need to add text to one line at a time. I would prefer not having to change the way the line is drawn, that is, the line should be drawn how it would be drawn without the text being there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[class=minimal,border=0pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[-] (-1,-0.5) .. controls (-1,1) and (1,0) .. 
    node[above left=-20pt and -11pt,align=center] 
    {\colorbox{yellow}{short line}\\\colorbox{yellow}{much longer line}} (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

You could also consider drawing the path on top

[image]

```
\documentclass[class=minimal,border=0pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[-] (-1,-0.5) .. controls (-1,1) and (1,0) .. 
    node[behind path, above left=-20pt and -11pt,align=center] 
    {\colorbox{yellow}{short line}\\\colorbox{yellow}{much longer line}} (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I suspected there was a key to do that but I would have had to read the manual:-) Thanks, I'll fix.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel done

Comment: Thanks, does exactly what I need. (Drawing the path on top of the text is not an option for me.)

Answer (score 2):

I think [David Carlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/679032/16595)'s solution is already a very good one because one need a new (multi-part) shape to have only the text be filled and not the whole rectangle while still have it act as one node.

If you don't need the node to be sloped (rotated along the path) you could use a `matrix` (of nodes).

Note that you need an ending `\\` here. We could also define a pic where the last `\\`  won't be necessary but will need the syntax

```
pic [<options>] {multiline = short line \\ much longer line}
```

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, matrix}
\tikzset{
  multiline/.style={
    matrix of nodes,
    every outer matrix/.append style={
      inner sep=+0pt, outer sep=+0pt, path only, shape=rectangle}}}
\begin{document}
\tikz
  \draw (-1,-0.5) .. controls (-1,1) and (1,0) ..
    node[
      multiline,
      above left = -20pt and -11pt,
      nodes={fill=yellow}
    ] {short line\\much longer line\\} (1,1);
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]