# "Tight" filling of multi-line text in node without affecting linespacing

Tags: tikz-pgf, line-spacing

This is a follow-up to ["Tight" filling of multi-line text in node](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/679031/tight-filling-of-multi-line-text-in-node/679032#679032), in which I was not clear enough about wanting the linespacing to be unaffected.

In brief, I need to overlay multi-line text on a curve. To ensure that
the text is on top of the curve, I color in the node containing the text.  Since there are multiple lines that differ in their lengths, the label looks odd when the entire node is coloured in. The [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/679032/18181) solved this problem, but does not address my (not clearly stated) need for the line spacing to be unaffected (for consistency with other multi-line labels in my figure).

Consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass[class=minimal]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[-] (-1,-0.5) .. controls (-1,1) and (1,0) .. 
    node[above left=-20pt and -11pt,align=center] 
    {\colorbox{yellow}{short line}\\\colorbox{yellow}{much longer line}} (1,1);
  \draw[-] (-0.105,0.576)  
    node[red,above left=-20pt and -11pt,align=center] 
    {short line\\much longer line};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which gives

[image]

The red text has the usual line spacing. The black text with the desired "tight" filling has a slightly larger line spacing.

How can I have "tight" filling of multi-line text in a node without changing the line spacing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

I meant to say you could set fboxep to 0 (which is 2 here) but I guess you prefer 3

```
\documentclass[class=minimal,border=0pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\newcommand\ya[1]{\colorbox{yellow}{#1}}
\newcommand\yb[1]{{\fboxsep=0pt\colorbox{yellow}{#1}}}
\newcommand\yc[1]{\vphantom{#1}\smash{\colorbox{yellow}{#1}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[-] (-1,-0.5) .. controls (-1,1) and (1,0) .. 
    node[above left=-20pt and -11pt,align=center] 
    {\ya{short line1}\\\ya{much longer line}} (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[-] (-1,-0.5) .. controls (-1,1) and (1,0) .. 
    node[above left=-20pt and -11pt,align=center] 
    {\yb{short line2}\\\yb{much longer line}} (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[-] (-1,-0.5) .. controls (-1,1) and (1,0) .. 
    node[above left=-20pt and -11pt,align=center] 
    {\yc{short line3}\\\yc{much longer line}} (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[-] (-1,-0.5) .. controls (-1,1) and (1,0) .. 
    node[above left=-20pt and -11pt,align=center] 
    {short line4\llap{\rule[-.5pt]{25cm}{.5pt}}\\%
     much longer line\llap{\rule[-.5pt]{25cm}{.5pt}}} (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```